# Electron Fetches Resources of React From Root Dir

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, electron

I spent the last week trying some of recipes to glue Electron + React, but, each of them has its cons.

Today, thought to do it by:

1. `create-react-app ...`
2. `npm install electron --save-dev`
3. Put all Electron logic into `build` dir of React (must do some work to keep theme there after the coming step 5, because it will clear `build` dir)
4. Using Electron's `window.loadURL('file://.../index.html')` (index.html) is react built HTML
5. `npm run build` (will build react app)
6. `npx electron ./build/main.js`

Wow! it worked like charm. But, there is only one conflict I need to know how to fix, which is:

React is writing links and sources as `/../..` which Electron understands as `root` directory of the system, and I have to add the `dot` manually before each `src` to be `./../..`, which fixed the conflict.

But, that would be almost impossible to do by hand for all the links in app! So, please, how can this done automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it today..

Just add property `"homepage" : "./"` to `package.json`,
[check this issue comment on create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/165#issuecomment-235801531)